# Check object type from cache List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I am having an issue was stored cache on a server, before is use to be stored as customerid, Listing and we are saving as a customer Id, List. What i would like to know if we have a method where i can see the value returned from the cache of what list and if List remove from cache what is the best method, i have code the emthod of reading from cache also

current mthod to read from cache

```
public async Task<List<CustomerModel>> Get(Guid customerId)
        {
            var customerMarketplaces = await _cacheClient.GetValue<List<CustomerModel>>(RootKey, customerId.ToString());

            return customerMarketplaces;
        }
```

old mthod to read from cache

```
public async Task<List<uint>> Get(Guid customerId)
        {
            var customerMarketplaces = await _cacheClient.GetValue<List<unit>>(RootKey, customerId.ToString());

            return customerMarketplaces;
        }
```

Cache return looking at key value pair

```
 public async Task<T> GetValue<T>(string rootKey, string itemKey) where T : class, new()
        {
            if (itemKey != null)
            {
                var key = $"{rootKey ?? DefaultCacheKey}-{itemKey.ToLowerInvariant()}";

                var value = await Redis().StringGetAsync(key);

                if (value != RedisValue.Null)
                {
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

what i am expecting is ideas about possible souution for issues.

Comment: If your search via a single Id why should it return a list?  It feels weird wanting a List of customers for a customerId. Besides that i have a hard time understanding the question. Can you rephrase?